# C block scope functions?

Tags: c

Is it possible to create a function that works on a block scope? Such as

Edited to clarify

```
enum { cannot, must };
int it(enum modal verb);

describe(fx) {
    context("some context") {
        it(must) { /* Some test that returns an int to it() */ };
    }
}
```

I doubt this is possible so what is the next best thing I can do?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do, and only one thing in your sample code has block scope (`verb` has block scope).  What do you mean by "works on block scope" (what does it do?)

Comment: such as keywords while, etc. A block scope is anything between `{}`

Comment: I know what block scope is, I don't know what "works on" is.  In your example, "verb" has block scope.  The "cannot", "must", and "it" identifiers have file scope.  The `while` keyword **does not** have scope, since it is not a valid identifier.

Comment: such as how `while() {}` works on it's own block scope. Maybe I don't fully understand scoping? I'll probably work on a macro of some kind

Comment: The term "block scope" applies to identifiers **only**.  For example, variables can have block scope.  Control structures (such as `while`) do not have scope, since they are not identifiers.  Braces `{}` are blocks.  Variables declared inside blocks have "block scope", e.g., `while (1) { int x; }` (x has block scope).  Can you give a complete example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks almost like Smalltalk or Ruby to me, which makes me think you want to pass *closures* (sometimes called *blocks*) to functions.  This is possible with various extensions to C, and there are also workarounds.

For example, maybe you want to iterate over a list:

```
{
    // this does not actually work, sorry
    iterate(list) { |i| -> printf("%d\n", i); }
}
```

If you are using Apple's extensions to C, you can use something called "blocks"

```
{
    // Apple only
    iterate(list, ^(int i) { printf("%d\n", i); });
}
```

You can also write a callback,

```
static void my_callback(int i) { printf("%d\n", i); }

...
{
    iterate(list, my_callback);
}
```

Callbacks can't access variables in scope in other functions, so you have to figure out a way to share variables.

And there are nested functions in GCC; these have access to scoped variables just like Apple's "blocks" extension.

```
{
    // GCC only
    void callback(int i) { printf "%d\n", i); }
    iterate(list, callback);
}
```

If you find yourself wanting to do this a lot, you may save yourself a lot of headache by switching to a language other than C.  C is not very friendly for higher-order programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, but perhaps the [nested function](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) extension of GCC answers your needs. Beware that it is a non-standard extension (and some other compilers don't give it).

Beware that C functions are (sadly) not [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29); this is a reason to switch to some functional language (like Ocaml, Haskell, Scheme ...).